# Performance issue on MySQL RDS with Play Framework EBean

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, playframework-2.0

I have faced a performance issue on RDS. I'm using Play Framework 2.1.1 with MySQL. The query that I'm testing takes about 2 seconds on my local unmodified MySQL database which I installed from brew on my Mac. But when I run the same query on MySQL RDS it takes about 12 seconds which is significantly slower than my local one and it baffles me.

Technology.

- Play framework 2.1.1
- MySQL 5.x.x
- MySQL RDS (Medium, 300GB, 5.5.27)

What I'm trying to achieve is a many-to-many sql mapping.

Here's my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class Product extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String code;
    public String title;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="OFFER_MAPPING",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="FK_U_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="FK_P_ID")})
    public List<Offer> offers = new ArrayList<Offer>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Offer")
public class Offer extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public DateTime startDate;
    public DateTime endDate;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="offers")
    public List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

}
```

And this is the Finder that I'm using

```
List<Offer> offers = new Model.Finder<Long, Offer>(Long.class, Offer.class)
                .fetch("products", new FetchConfig().query())
                .where()
                .betweenProperties("startDate", "endDate", new DateTime())
                .findList();
```

which generates this sql

```
select t0.id c0, t0.start_date c1, t0.end_date c2
        , t1.id c3, t1.code c4, t1.title c5 
from Offer t0
left outer join Offer t1z_ on t1z_.FK_P_ID = t0.id 
left outer join PRODUCTS t1 on t1.id = t1z_.FK_U_ID  
where  '2013-04-26'  between t0.start_date and t0.end_date 
order by t0.id;
```

And I run this query in MySQL which took MySQL RDS 12 seconds to spit out the result.

Any suggestion is welcome from EBean, SQL Statement or RDS. Thanks very much.

Comment: The question I would ask is why does this query even take 2 seconds in your local environment? My guess is you need to look at making sure you have proper indexing and rewriting the WHERE clause to be something like `WHERE t0.start_date >= '2013-04-26' AND t0.end_date <= '2013-04-26'`. 2 seconds is way too long for a query that looks to be relatively straightforward unless you are returning a large amount of data.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out here as well. I use EBean from Play Framework. So, the SQL is generated from EBean.

Comment: And yeah, the data is relatively big. It's about 4 million records.

Comment: But how many rows is the data being returned?  You can easily query off tables with millions of rows in sub-second timeframes if they are properly index and the indexes are fully in memory. Now if you are returning millions of rows of data, obviously there is not much that can be done about transmitting that large of a result set.

Comment: Good point and thanks for the fast reply. The data being returned is just 1000 rows. I'll have a look at my index again. However, there's still the question why RDS takes much longer with the same query and same data?

Comment: It could be any number of things.  You probably have different hardware, different MySQL memory settings, etc. Take a look at teh differences in your server variables between both systems to see if there are significant config differences, particularly your `innodb*` variables (I am assuming you are using innodb tables here). Check `key_buffer_size` if using MyISAM (which you really shouldn't be in MySQL 5.5 unless you have a specific need)